# Incorrect use of regex wildcards

Tags: regex, scala

This is not correct use of wildcards ? I'm attempting to match String that contains a date. I don't want to include the date in the returned String or the String value that prepends the matched String.

```
object FindText extends App{

  val toFind = "find1"
  val line = "this is find1 the line 1    \n  21/03/2015"
  val find = (toFind+".*\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}").r
  println(find.findFirstIn(line))

}
```

Output should be : "find1 the line 1    \n  "

but String is not found.

Comment: Are you sure you posted the right code? It doesn't look like this should even compile (you got an odd number of quotes and regex characters outside of the string).

Comment: @sepp2k sorry, question updated

Comment: From what I understand, it must be something like: [`val v = "find1" // val line = "this is find1 the line 1    \n  21/03/2015" // val toFind = ("""(?s) """ + Regex.quote(v) + """.*(?=\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})""").r`](https://ideone.com/PZNpb8).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dot does not match newline characters by default. You can set a DOTALL flag to make it happen (I have also added a "positive look-ahead - the `(?=...)` thingy - since you did not want the date to be included in the match": `val find = (toFind+"""(?s).*(?=\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})""").r`

(Note also, that in scala you do not need to escape special characters in strings, enclosed in a triple-quote pairs ... pretty neat).

Comment: This regex will match the date and return it as a result. OP does not say the date must be in the result.

Comment: What if `toFind` contains a `(` Or `[`?

Comment: Yeah ... or `.`, or `*`, or `?` ...  In that case, one would have to escape it. It would be a different question though, not one about using wildcards to match newlines ;)

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies with the newline in the test string. A `.*` does not match newlines apparently. Replacing this with `.*\\n?.*` should fix it. One could also use a multiline flag in the regex such as:

```
val find = ("(?s)"+toFind+".*\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}").r
```

Comment: *Output should be : "find1 the line 1 \n "* - did you check what output you get with the above regex?

Comment: You are correct, this will include the date in the match.